# Undefined index error in PHP file (passing value from Android file)

Tags: php, android

Please help me to find the error in below code.

I have posted a value from an Android file through `namevaluepair` to a PHP file.

I am getting the below error:

> Notice: Undefined index: city {"result":[]}

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sampledb";
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
$city = $_POST['city'];
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$stmtsearch = "SELECT a.title, a.phone, a.description, a.email, a.post_date FROM `ad_master` a INNER JOIN tbl_city_master b ON a.city_id = b.fld_city_id WHERE b.fld_city_name = '$city'";
$resultsearch = $con->query($stmtsearch);
$json = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsearch)) {
    array_push($json, array(
        'title' => $row[0],
        'phone' => $row[1],
        'description' => $row[2],
        'email' => $row[3],
        'post_date' => $row[4]
    ));
}
echo json_encode(array("result" => $json));
$con->close();
?>
```

Android code:

```
public void getData() {
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            Intent in = getIntent();
            String city = in.getStringExtra(("city"));
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/qsearchdetail.php");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception squish) {
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            myJSON = result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g=new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}

public void showList() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        search = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);
        for (int i = 0; i < search.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = search.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
            String postDate = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
            HashMap<String, String> search = new HashMap<String, String>();

            search.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
            search.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);
            search.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
            search.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
            search.put(TAG_DATE, postDate);
            searchList.add(search);
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            QResultDetail.this,searchList, R.layout.search_result,
            new String[]{TAG_TITLE, TAG_PHONE, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_DESCRIPTION,TAG_DATE},
            new int[] { R.id.tvTitle, R.id.tvMobile, R.id.tvEmail, R.id.tvDesp, R.id.tvDate }
        );
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your php code should start with checking if the city parameter comes in. Use isset() to check. If not set then send an error messge right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending your `nameValuePairs`.